# Does Nifi 1.10 PutSplunk support Expression Language for the Port?

Tags: apache-nifi

Looking at the documentation for PutSplunk, it says that the Port "**Supports Expression Language: true (will be evaluated using variable registry only)**", does this mean I can't use expression language? Depending on the data in my flow, I want to have a single PutSplunk processor that handles the different ports I need to send my data to my Splunk instance.

Is there a way around this, because when I use **${splunkPort}** in PutSplunk, I receive this error message: **NumberFormatException: For input string""**

For your convenience, here is the PutSplunk documentation link: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-splunk-nar/1.10.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.splunk.PutSplunk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `variable registry` option in `nifi.properties`. You can refer a file with this option such as

```
nifi.variable.registry.properties=test.txt
```

where the test.txt should have keys and values.

```
port=1234
url=abc.com
```

Then, you can refer to the variable port by `${port}`.

> Supports Expression Language: true (will be evaluated using variable registry only)

There are many types of variables but in this case, the variables from the registry only can be evaluated, that is the meaning.

Comment: Thanks @Lamanus, I misunderstood this entirely. I'm still new to NiFi, but I thought that I could apply an Attribute to the Port so I could maintain a single PutSplunk Processor instead of having multiple PutSplunk Processors that just have a different port. So this is the correct answer to my question, but I asked the wrong question. So I take it, it is not possible to apply FlowFile Attribute to the PutSplunk Port field.